# Target framework in VB.NET project

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working on a Visual Basic project using Visual Studio Community 2013, running on Windows 7 SP1 with .NET Framework 4.5.1. In my project properties I changed target framework from 4.5.1 to 4.5. When I try to install my application on another computer running Windows 7 SP1 with .NET 4.5, I get the following error message: "A failure occured attempting to install the .NET Framework 4.5.1"

Why won't my application install on a computer with .NET 4.5 when I have built/published the application with target framework set to .NET 4.5?

I tried creating a new project with target framework set to 4.5, and I have no problems installing this new application. When creating my main project, I did set target framework to 4.5.1 and later changed it to 4.5. I am thinking that maybe my main project was created with some kind of "template" for 4.5.1 ??

Comment: Did you change the Target Framework in the Propperties of the "Code-Project" or in the Properties of the Installer? Which Installer do you use?

Comment: I changed the target framework by clicking Project->Properties in VS. I don't use any installer (as far as I know), I clicked Project->Publish and VS created a publish directory with a setup.exe and with some other files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you copy the EXE directly from the Debug folder and run it?

Comment: No I got an error message: "This is not a valid Win32 application"

Comment: do you have an msi file along with the setup as well? if yes, have you tried running that??

Comment: along with setup.exe there are some .application and .deploy and .manifest files, but no .msi file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question [ClickOnce won't install .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263262/clickonce-wont-install-net-4-5):

> Try Project Properties -> Publish -> Prerequisites -> Change to the
>   framework you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! That seems very likely to solve it. (Not been able to try it on other computer yet)